# 1 Error "ResolveManifestFiles" System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range. WPF C# Desktop app

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, desktop, visual-studio-2013

Im tray to compile a Visual Studio Solution and get this error.

> Error 1   Error inesperado en la tarea "ResolveManifestFiles".
>   System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.NativeMethods.GetAssemblyIdentityFromFile(String filePath, Guid& riid)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.MetadataReader.ImportAttributes()
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.MetadataReader.get_Attributes()
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.MetadataReader.get_Name()
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.AssemblyIdentity.FromManagedAssembly(String path)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles.IsFiltered(ITaskItem item)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles.GetOutputAssemblies(PublishInfo[] publishInfos, List`1& assemblyList)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles.GetOutputAssembliesAndSatellites(PublishInfo[] assemblyPublishInfos, PublishInfo[] satellitePublishInfos)
>      at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>      at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext() Ziruma

Im not sure what is the problem. Project compiling until i try to generate the final instalation package. Please, help me.